# Is there an LLVM-based programming language that can guarantee sandbox-safe fast binaries?

Tags: security, llvm, sandbox

I am writing a computationally-heavy code for a server (in C/C++). In the inside loops, I need to call some **external user functions**, millions of times, so they have to run natively fast and their invocation should have no more overhead than a C function call. Each time I receive a user function, in source form, I will automatically compile it into binary and it will be dynamically linked by the main code.

Those functions will only be used as simple Math kernels, e.g. in a peudo-C:

```
Function f(double x) ->double {
  return x * x;
}
```

or with array access:

```
Function f(double* ar, int length) ->double {
  double sum = 0;
  for(i = 0 to length) {
    sum = sum + ar[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

or with basic math library calls:

```
Function f(double x) ->double {
  return cos(x);
}
```

However, they have to be safe for the server. It's OK if they halt (Turing completeness), but not if they **access process memory** that is not their own, if they do **system calls**, if they cause **stack overflow**, or to generalize, it's unwanted for the external code to "**be able to hack the server code**".

So my question: I'm wandering if there is a safe-by-design language with an LLVM frontend, (with no pointers etc., with bound checking for arrays/stack, isolation of system calls), with no speed penalties (referring to supervisors, garbage collectors), that I can use. LLVM is not necessary, but it's preferred.

I had a look at Mozillas "Rust" but it doesn't seem to be safe enough [[rust-dev]](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2014-January/008061.html).

If there is no such language my fallback option right now is to use a NodeJS Sandboxed VM.

I believe that such a language, if made simple, is feasible but does it exist?

The type of language doesn't matter. A toy language with simplistic design and easy to prove safety would do.

EDIT: Concerning the system calls and harmful dependencies, for any language, it should be easy enough to isolate them with plain *bash*. Just try to link the produced .bc with no libraries. If it fails, the .bc has dependencies, so drop it. Since LLVM IR are otherwise totally harmless, the only thing that should be guaranteed by the language is memory access.

Comment: Very interesting question. Might be off-topic here, though, as it is asking for pointers to off-site resources.

Comment: Did you consider PNaCl?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thank you for your comment. I think it would be informative though, and still the rule is not exactly my case since I am asking about the existence of something not too common.

Comment: @EliBendersky Yes, I somehow skipped it though assuming from what I read about it that it may add some layer of complication, a supervisor, and possibly some (costly?) overhead each time the method is invoked. That however was only my impression since I didn't find enough resources about it.

Comment: It sounds like a perfect match to your requirements - I suggest you read more about it. Start here: https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/nacl-and-pnacl

Answer (score 2):

I would really like to add a comment, however Stack-Overflow is preventing me.  So I'll just add it as an answer.  Perhaps it will be useful.

You might try looking at https://github.com/andoma/vmir.  I have been working with it a bit with the hopes of sandboxing arbitrary c++/swift code.  I think, it might be possible to create a "safe" interpreter/JIT.

You can control all functions which are called.  You can control how memory is accessed.  So...  Basically, I think, (and am hoping), that I can modify the JIT and interpreter enough so that I can reject code which is inherently not safe, and put up memory boundaries/function restrictions.

Having distinct processes ala PNaCL is the obvious sandboxing choice, but the overhead is substantial.  I believe the sandboxing is done process wise.

Comment: This sounds interesting, however your README talks about a runtime overhead. I am wondering if there is, somewhere, an answer involving safety achieved by the compiler (hosted in-house) and not by sandbox

Comment: @tikwi I wonder if you could look at java or c# compiled to machine code. (with a custom system class path). The garbage collection aspects of the languages is unfortunate, but...